# How to add autocomplete for foreign key using autocomplete_fields

Tags: django, django-models

I have following model

```
from django.db import models

class Ipaddress(models.Model):
    ipaddress=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    machinename=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    department= models.ForeignKey('Department',on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='Empty')
    location= models.ForeignKey('Location', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateField("Date Updated",null=True)
    note =models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ipaddress[:50]
```

In the admin page:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from pages.models import Post, Device, DeviceType, DeviceModel, Ipaddress, DeviceGroup, Location,Department,Comment
from django_admin_listfilter_dropdown.filters import DropdownFilter, RelatedDropdownFilter


class IpaddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('ipaddress',)}

    search_fields = ['ipaddress', ]

    list_display = ('ipaddress', 'machinename', 'user', 'department','location','updated',)
    list_filter = (
    ('user', DropdownFilter),
    ('department', RelatedDropdownFilter),
    ('location', RelatedDropdownFilter),

)
```

When I try to add a device it shows following page:
The location of the list could be a few thousand racks. So, i need to type the rack instead of scrolling 1000 of records. Any idea how i can do that.

Comment: Do you have a template or are you using the admin panel ?

Comment: i am using admin panel

Answer (score 1):

Until someone shares a complex solution i suggest you add your **ForeignKey** Location to your search_fields instead like:

`search_fields = ['foreign_key__related_fieldname']`

So if your "location names" are defined with the field 'title' in your Location model you could do:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Ipaddress

class IpaddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['ipaddress', 'location__title']

admin.site.register(Ipaddress, IpaddressAdmin)
```

*Note: stripped it down to the essential in this example that assumes this is in app/admin.py and that the Ipadress model is in app/models.py*

This is really convenient since django admin breaks down multiple search words (seperated by spaces) so you can search for "ip location" like:

**127.0.0.1 Sweden**

And it would search both your 'ipadress' field and your ForeignKey 'Location'.

Pros:

- **Fast!** No need to reload the view twice if you need to search after applying filter!
- Simple

Cons:

- Possibly slower querying if one adds many foreign keys for search_fields or has a huge amount of objects in the foreign key model.

Django 2.1 docs: [ModelAdmin.search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)